# Mouse events during window.alert/window.confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a custom drag method consisting of `mousedown, mouseup and mousemove` events, like this. My method is - `move()`

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function() {drag = true });
$(document).on('mouseup', function() {drag = false });
$(document).on('mousemove', function() { if (drag) move() });
```

It all works perfectly but imagine this `move()` declaration:

```
function move() {
  confirm('Do you blablabla...?');
}
```

Now the sequence is this:

1. I click on document
2. I move mouse
3. I get a confirm modal box
4. I click Ok/Cancel
5. I move mouse
6. I get a confirm modal box

**I get confirm modal box despite the fact I have my mouse button released.** It turns out there are no events reported while modal box is being displayed.

**MY QUESTION -** how to get around this?

I though only of one possible solution - override window.alert/window.confirm with a custom modal box(like jQuery UI Modal) but in this case I would like to keep defaults and the application is mature enough so users are used to default looking of modals.

**HOW I FIXED IT?**

I did this:

```
  var _alert = window.alert;
  var _confirm = window.confirm;

  window.alert = function() {
    drag = false;
    return _alert.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  window.confirm = function() {
    drag = false;
    return _confirm.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

And it pretty much works for me without introducing new bugs. I will appreciate any insigt into this solution though.

Comment: I would say a custom dialog (jquery UI?) would be a simple answer.  You could just override the existing confirm method if changing your existing code is the issue.

Comment: @Archer I agree but the problem is - the application is mature enough and users like consistend UX. Changing default modals would be out of the blue :/

Comment: I guarantee that your users will thank you for getting rid of alert and confirm dialogs and using something better :)

Comment: @Archer the problem with this is that there may be undefined behaviour somewhere in the application. It really sounds quick and easy, but changing one of the default methods all over the big system raises my adrenaline levels :)

Comment: You obviously don't want to do it, and that's fine - I'm not saying you should if you don't want to, but `alert` and `confirm` have such specific functionality that you *can* change them system-wide and not worry.  Good luck though - I hope you find what you're looking for :)

Comment: Can't be changed, but styled to look like the old ones?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar I am a pessimist in software design. I don't take for granted window.alert = myCustomFunction() very well. My experience proved innocent places becoming root of bugs :) call me stupid if you want or defensive

Comment: Oh I didn't mean override window.alert - that would be silly.... as bad as 'undefined = false;' ! But I need mean replacing the calls to window.alert() with another function - admittedly a bit of work..

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar thats the solution which seems to be working for me! See update :)

Comment: What does the Drag=false do? If you've solved it, you'd be better submitted it as an answer - then you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar it's just a flag mousemove handler uses :)

Comment: But isn't it scoped to the function? It's not passed anywhere....?

Answer (score 1):

The modal will cause the events to be halted, as you're not longer clicking on the page/body.

The best solution would be your own rolled dialog with styling.

Try http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Thanks for your input. But isn't there another way..? :)

Comment: Not really, the modals are implemented by the browser as a result of JS firing, so it's pretty much beyond your control...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation though!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue with quite a simple code. Despite fearing modifying original methods, I tried to keep the original ones in place.

Code simply sets the drag flag to false once a modal or alert is being displayed.

```
  var _alert = window.alert;
  var _confirm = window.confirm;

  window.alert = function() {
    drag = false;
    return _alert.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  window.confirm = function() {
    drag = false;
    return _confirm.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar there's 2 days delay :)